# How to create horizontal tabs using FAPI?

Tags: forms, 8

I have a custom form where I need to group fields with horizontal tabs, seems Drupal Core doesn't have something similar for horizontal tabs like it has for vertical tabs, I'm constrained to use Drupal Core API (no contrib dependencies).

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I don't see how this can even be possible without using Field Group module and extending it. Create your own field group type..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use twig template + JQuery for it ?

That is, you create a twig template for your form, add it to your theme and also add the [JQuery widget for Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default) ?